# How would you say "I heard old war drums beat." in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, accusativus-cum-infinitivo, consecutio-temporum

See [this question on English Language Learners StackExchange](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/338857/165841) for context. My attempt to say it in Latin would be "*Audivi vetera belli tympana tunsa fuisse.*". Is that correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, past events in an AcI are expressed by the perfect infinitive, which in the passive is the perfect participle + *esse*. So you should write *Audivi … tympana tunsa esse*, except that the indirect speech narrates a present event (direct speech: *tympana tunduntur*), so it ought to be *Audivi … tympana tundi*.

Which is fine, I guess, but does not very well capture the English original, in my opinion. It literally translates to: "I heard that old war drums were being beaten," which is not quite the same as "I heard the drums beat" (for one, it could be interpreted such that you did not hear the drums themselves, but somebody told you abou them – and the same is true of the Latin). Also, I think you *pellere* a *tympanum*, not *tundere*.

Therefore I would rather suggest a freer translation, such as: **Audivi veterum tympanorum bellicorum pulsum** – literally: "I heard the beat of old war drums"; for example, *cymbalorum at tympanorum pulsus* is invoked by Livy in his history of Rome (39, 10, also *strepitus* in ch. 8, both times talking about depraved religious rituals).

Answer (score 4):

Sebastian's is a good suggestion, and I too don't recommend using an indirect statement here, but rather a participle, which would make it more vivid* (see [A&G §497 d](https://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/uses-participles)).
<sub>*More vivid than the indirect statement, that is.</sub>

So:

> Audivi vetera tympana resonantia Bellonae.
> I heard the resounding of the old drums of Bellona.

Cf. Sil. It. 17.19:

> certabant rauco resonantia tympana pulsu

Why *bellona*? Because she's the goddess of war, War personified. *Martis* would also be good, but choosing Bellona here gives it a more archaic and martial flavor, in my opinion.

Also, using *resonantia* adds an ambiguity that might play nicely in a poem. Are the drums "of Bellona" (gen.), or are they echoing her (dat.)? Ambiguity here can add to the mystical nature of the drumming. If you should want to lean into the mystery, you could even use *antiqua* instead of *vetera*.

However, I should note the mysticism isn't present in Bogle's song, so while I think this is a great phrase without that context, if you were trying to capture Bogle's context as well, I would substitute *Martis* for *Bellonae*. This would, unfortunately, remove the intentional ambiguity.